# XCode: Project portability: How to handle code files shared between applications?

Tags: xcode, file, project, shared

As I create more applications, my /code/shared/* increases.

this creates a problem:  zipping and sending a project is no longer trivial. it looks like my options are:

1. in Xcode set shared files to use absolute path. Then every time I zip and send,  I must also zip and send /code/shared/*  and give instructions, and hope the recipient doesn't have anything already at that location.
   this is really not practical; it makes the zip file too big
2. maintain a separate copy of my library files for each project
   this is not really acceptable as a modification/improvements would have to be implemented everywhere separately.   this makes maintenance unreasonably cumbersome.
3. some utility  to go through every file in the Xcode project, figure out the lowest common folder,  and create a zipped file structure that only contains the necessary files,  but in their correct relative folder locations, so that the code will still build

(3) is what I'm looking for, but I have a feeling it doesn't as yet exist.

Anyone?

Answer (score -1):

You should rethink your current process. The workflow you're describing in (3) is not normal. This all sounds very complicated and all basically handled with relative ease if you were using source control. (3) just doesn't exist and likely never will.

A properly configured SCM will allow you to manage multiple versions of multiple libraries (packages) and allow you to share projects (in branches) without ever requiring zipping up anything.